# Criar um nome para uma variável com o php

Tags: php

Bom estou com uma questão onde o próprio php tem que criar o nome da variável, já usei esse recursos várias vezes. O problema que agora estou tentando usar isso em um array, da seguinte forma:

```
// Cria o nome da variável
$tabela = "tabela1";

// Cria o array
$$tabela[1] = array(
    "valor" => $valor
);
```

Bom o código tinha que criar uma variável com o nome `$tabela1` e colocar o array nela, porém ele esta me retornando esse erro:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in teste.php on line 3
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: este é um array multi dimensional? Acredito que o que está errado é $$tabela[] = array..., deveria ser $$tabela = array...

Comment: Na verdade uso o `[]` para fazer a ligação dos dados. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Queres que `$tabela` seja um array é isso? e na posição 1 que valor queres que tenha?

Comment: Não quero criar uma variável com o nome `tabela1` e depois colocar um array nela.

Comment: Porque não usar somente `$tabela1` assim: https://ideone.com/VIQsRv ?

Comment: Então tenho um `for` onde tenho que criar alguns arrays, e fica mais fácil o próprio código criar os nomes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema estava ocorrendo no $$tabela[1], neste ponto, o PHP tenta definir o índice de um array que não existe ainda, você precisa colocar em volta da variável `chaves` para o PHP entender que primeiro ele precisa criar a variável e depois definir o índice dela. O correto ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

// Cria o nome da variável
$tabela = "tabela1";

$valor = "Qualquer coisa";

// Cria o array
${$tabela}[1] = array(
    "valor" => $valor
); 

?>
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você cria o array depois você atribui os valores.

```
// Cria o nome da variável
$tabela = "tabela1";

// Cria o array
$$tabela = array();

// Atribui os valores
$$tabela[1] = array(
    "valor" => $valor
);
```

Comment: Dessa forma não funcionou no meu código, mas a forma do @Bruno Rigolon deu certo.

Comment: Eu testei aqui com PHP 7 e funcionou de boa, mas a resposta do @Bruno Rigolon é mais correta de se fazer. ;)